# Typescript error: It is not assignable to parameter of type (same type different folder)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am currently working on aws cdk, where I am using Typescript for the setup. I have a question, where I have same library but they are referred as not same type.

Compilation Error:

```
Argument of type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-output").CfnOutput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-output").CfnOutput'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property '_description'.
```

```
Argument of type 'CdkCloudFormationAppreciationDashboardStage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stage'.
  Types of property '_assemblyBuilder' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly").CloudAssemblyBuilder' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly").CloudAssemblyBuilder'.
      Types have separate declarations of a private property 'artifacts'.ts(2345)
```

Code:

```
 // This is where we add the application stages
   const preprod = new CdkCloudFormationAppreciationDashboardStage(this, 'PreProd', {
    env: { account: 'accountnumber', region: 'ap-southeast-1' },
  });

  // put validations for the stages 
  const preprodStage = pipeline.addApplicationStage(preprod);
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "^1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline": "^1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions": "^1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "^1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/pipelines": "^1.122.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.83",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
```

Full Logs:

```
> cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard@0.1.0 build
> tsc

lib/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard-pipeline.ts:40:9 - error TS2322: Type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/secret-value").SecretValue' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/secret-value").SecretValue'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'value'.

40         oauthToken: SecretValue.secretsManager('devhour-backend-git-access-token', {jsonField: 'devhour-backend-git-access-token'}), // this token is stored in Secret Manager
           ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions/lib/github/source-action.d.ts:118:14
    118     readonly oauthToken: SecretValue;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'oauthToken' which is declared here on type 'GitHubSourceActionProps'

lib/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard-pipeline.ts:61:53 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'CdkCloudFormationAppreciationDashboardStage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stage'.
  Types of property '_assemblyBuilder' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly").CloudAssemblyBuilder' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly").CloudAssemblyBuilder'.
      Types have separate declarations of a private property 'artifacts'.

61   const preprodStage = pipeline.addApplicationStage(preprod);
                                                       ~~~~~~~

lib/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard-pipeline.ts:68:42 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-output").CfnOutput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/Smit/Documents/Dev/aws-cdk/cdk-cloud-formation-appreciation-dashboard/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-codestarnotifications/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/cfn-output").CfnOutput'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property '_description'.

68       ENDPOINT_URL: pipeline.stackOutput(preprod.urlOutput),
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that you Aws-cdk packages are all the same version.

Set them all on 1.122.0, don't use ^. Not good practice, things change very ofton in cdk.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.122.0",
    "@aws-cdk/pipelines": "1.122.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.83",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }
```